# Difference between create table and create table as

Tags: mysql

Is there a difference between

```
create table table1 as
select * from table 2;
```

and

```
create table table1
select * from table 2;
```

What does the keyword "as" do in this case?

Comment: Nothing. It is optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AS` keyword is optional when creating a table that takes the columns and data types of a SELECT result set. You can use the `AS` if it makes the statement more readable for you, but it is not required.

I agree with the comment from @spencer7593 that the keyword has no effect.

You can spot optional syntax if you refer to syntax documentation. For example, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html documents the syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl [AS] SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
```

It's customary for square-brackets in syntax documentation to signify an optional part.

For what it's worth, `AS` is optional in some other cases in SQL, like defining column aliases or table aliases.

Comment: To reemphasize the point (beyond just being "optional") including or omitting the `AS` keyword has *no effect* on the statement. (But this doesn't hold true for all "optional" keywords, some of them *do* have an effect.)

Comment: +1 . . . Although I don't think "You can use the `AS`" is quite strong enough.  I would highly recommend always using `as` for both `create table` and column aliases (but not for table aliases).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, do you have a functional reason for that recommendation? I prefer it too, but for stylistic reasons.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . Not for the `create table`; that would be stylistic.  For column aliases, it is because without the `as`, it is easy to put in a comma and change the list of columns.  For table aliases, it is a combination of simplifying the query and the fact that Oracle doesn't support `as` in the `from` statement.